# Is it possible to calculate page load time (including that of the requests made from inside the page) on server side in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, performance, metrics

In my ASP.NET website, I want to get the full time it takes to serve the page including the requests made from inside the page. I want to do this on the server side. It is easy to do this for individual requests in Global.asax but deciding if the current request is part of a particular page that is loading on client is not as trivial. Any ideas how could this be done?

Answer (score 0):

First calculate individual requests in Global.asax and then I think if there is any other request(Ajax) on client side then calculate it on client and after that sum up both, If your Ajax call is also request to your server then you can calculate on that particular call completion time on server side but if your ajax call request some other server then i think you have to calculate it on client side.

To make use of the Application Class, add a new Global.asax page to your ASP.NET web application and add the below code to it.

```
public void Application_BeginRequest(object src, EventArgs e)
{
    Context.Items["loadstarttime"] = DateTime.Now;
}

public void Application_EndRequest(object src, EventArgs e)
{
    DateTime end = (DateTime)Context.Items["loadstarttime"];
    TimeSpan loadtime = DateTime.Now - end;
    Response.Write("&lt;h3&gt;This page took " + loadtime + "ms to load&lt;/h3&gt;");
}
```

The above code will execute whenever a page in your web application is requested. BeginRequest event will fire whenever a new request is received and EndRequest will fire when the request is processed. We make use of the Items collection of the Context class to store and retrieve the initial time when the request is received. Now the time taken for the page to load will be displayed in each page of your web application whenever each of it is requested.